# First derivative of matrix expression

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Can someone help me find the first derivative of the following function $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to the elements $\phi_{mn}$ of the matrix $\mathbf{\Phi}$?

\begin{equation} 
\mathcal{L} =  -\frac{1}{2}\big[\log\left|\mathbf{C}\right| - 2\left[ \mathbf{t}\log\left(\sigma\big(\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{w}\big)\right) + (1-\mathbf{t})\log\left(1-\sigma\big(\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{w}\big)\right)  \right] + \mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{w}\big]
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation} 
\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}, \\
\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{B^{-1}} + \mathbf{\Phi} \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{\Phi}^{T}, \\
\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{B^{-1}}\mathbf{S}\mathbf{\Phi}^{T}\mathbf{t}, \\
\end{equation}

Note that bold small letters denote $N\times 1$ vectors, bold capital letters $N\times N$ matrices, $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$ are diagonal, and the sigmoid function $\sigma(x)$ is element-wise for vector input.

I earlier asked for a somewhat similar derivative where the $\log\left|\mathbf{C}\right|$ term appeared as well. The excellent and detailed answer to it (which might be helpful for this problem) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422933/steps-in-derivative-of-matrix-expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the previous linked question, replace $\,{\rm log}({\rm det}({\bf C}))$ with $\,{\rm tr}({\rm log}({\bf C}))$.

Then you need to know the trick for the finding derivative of scalar function applied element-wise to a matrix argument.  Assume that you have a scalar function $f(x)$ whose derivative is known to be $f'(x)$.  When you apply this element-wise to a matrix, the differential is
$$\eqalign{
  df({\bf X}) &= f'({\bf X})\circ d{\bf X} \cr
}$$
where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product.

For the logistic function, the derivative is known to be: $\,\,\,\sigma' = \sigma - \sigma^2$.

Actually, you are you are taking logarithms of the logistic function, so the derivatives are
$$\eqalign{
  \frac{d\,{\rm log}(\sigma(x))}{dx} &= \frac{\sigma-\sigma^2}{\sigma} = 1-\sigma \cr
  \frac{d\,{\rm log}(1-\sigma(x))}{dx} &= \frac{-(\sigma-\sigma^2)}{1-\sigma} = -\sigma \cr
}$$

Now we can put all of these pieces together.
$$\eqalign{
 -2\,L &= {\rm tr}({\rm log}({\bf C})) + {\bf A}:{\bf w}{\bf w}^T -2\,{\bf t}:{\rm log}(\sigma) -2\,(1-{\bf t}):{\rm log}(1-\sigma) \cr
 -2\,dL &= {\bf C}^{-1}:d{\bf C} + {\bf A}:2\,{\rm sym}(d{\bf w}\,{\bf w}^T)-2\,{\bf t}:(1-\sigma)\circ d{\bf x} -2\,(1-{\bf t}):(-\sigma)\circ d{\bf x} \cr
 &= {\bf C}^{-1}:d{\bf C} + 2\,{\bf A}:d{\bf w}\,{\bf w}^T-2\,{\bf t}\circ(1-\sigma):d{\bf x} +2\,(1-{\bf t})\circ\sigma:d{\bf x} \cr
 &= {\bf C}^{-1}:d{\bf C} + 2\,{\bf A}{\bf w}:d{\bf w} +2\,(\sigma-{\bf t}):d{\bf x} \cr
}$$
Now we just need to find expressions for {$d{\bf C},d{\bf w},d{\bf x}$} in terms of $d{\bf\Phi}$.
$$\eqalign{
 {\bf w} &= {\bf B^{-1}S\Phi^T\,t} \cr
d{\bf w} &= {\bf B^{-1}S}\,d{\bf \Phi^T\,t} \cr\cr
 {\bf x} &= {\bf \Phi w} \cr
d{\bf x} &= d{\bf \Phi}\,{\bf w} + {\bf \Phi}d{\bf w} \cr
   &= d{\bf \Phi}\,{\bf w} + {\bf \Phi B^{-1}S}\,d{\bf \Phi^T\,t} \cr\cr
 {\bf C} &= {\bf B^{-1}+\Phi A^{-1} \Phi^T} \cr
d{\bf C} &= 2\,{\rm sym}(d{\bf \Phi A^{-1} \Phi^T}) \cr\cr
}$$
Substituting
$$\eqalign{
-2\,dL &= {\bf C}^{-1}:2\,{\rm sym}(d{\bf \Phi A^{-1} \Phi^T}) + 2\,{\bf Aw}:{\bf B^{-1}S}\,d{\bf \Phi^T\,t} \cr
&+2\,(\sigma-{\bf t}):(d{\bf \Phi}\,{\bf w} + {\bf \Phi B^{-1}S}\,d{\bf \Phi^T\,t}) \cr\cr 
&= 2\,{\bf C}^{-1}{\bf \Phi A^{-1}}:d{\bf \Phi} + 2\,{\bf (S^TB^{-1}Awt^T)^T}:d{\bf \Phi} \cr
 &+2\,{\bf (\sigma-t)w^T}:d{\bf \Phi} +2\,{\bf (S^TB^{-1}\Phi^T(\sigma-t)t^T)^T}:d{\bf \Phi}\cr\cr
 dL &= \big[{\bf (t-\sigma)w^T + t(t-\sigma)^T\Phi B^{-1}S -tw^TAB^{-1}S - C^{-1}\Phi A^{-1}}\big]:d{\bf \Phi}\cr\cr
}$$
Finally, the expression for the gradient is
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial L}{\partial {\bf \Phi}} &= {\bf (t-\sigma)w^T + t(t-\sigma)^T\Phi B^{-1}S -tw^TAB^{-1}S - C^{-1}\Phi A^{-1}} \cr
}$$

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I will try on my own for some time, but then make a new question for the second derivative which I still need.

Comment: I have a question: Where did you learn to do this, can you maybe recommend me a textbook covering this kind of matrix calculus?