# First derivative of RVM related matrix expression

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Can somebody help me find the first of the following function $\mathcal{L}$ with respect to the elements $\phi_{mn}$ of the matrix $\mathbf{\Phi}$?

\begin{equation} 
\mathcal{L} =  -\frac{1}{2}\big[N\log 2\pi + \log\left|\mathbf{C}\right| + \mathbf{\hat{t}}^{T}\mathbf{C}^{-1}\mathbf{\hat{t}} \big], 
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{\Phi} \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{\Phi}^{T}, \\
\mathbf{\hat{t}} = \mathbf{\Phi}\boldsymbol{w} + \mathbf{B}^{-1}\mathbf{e}.
\end{equation}

Note that bold small letters denote $N\times 1$ vectors, bold capital letters $N\times N$ matrices, and $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$ are diagonal.

Background information: $\mathcal{L}$ is a likelihood function and relates to the Relevance Vector Machine (RVM) as described in the following [paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume1/tipping01a/tipping01a.pdf).

EDIT:

I came so far on my own for the first derivative of the last term (the first two terms were already answered in my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422933/steps-in-derivative-of-matrix-expression)). I first expanded it to get

\begin{align} 
\mathbf{\hat{t}}^{T}\mathbf{C}^{-1}\mathbf{\hat{t}} 
~=~&\mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}^{T}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{w} \\ ~+~&\mathbf{e}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{w} \\
~+~&\mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}^{T}\mathbf{e} \\
~+~&\mathbf{e}^{T}\mathbf{B}^{-T}\mathbf{e} \\
~-~&\mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Phi}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{w} \\ 
~-~&\mathbf{e}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Phi}^{T}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{w} \\ 
~-~&\mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Phi}^{T}\mathbf{e} \\ 
~-~&\mathbf{e}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Phi}^{T}\mathbf{e}.
\end{align}

Then I took the derivatives for terms number 1,2,3, and 8 on the right hand side using formulas from the matrix [cookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)

\begin{equation} 
\frac{\partial \left[ \mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}^{T}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{w} \right]}{\partial \mathbf{\Phi}} = 2 \mathbf{B}\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}^{T} \\
\frac{\partial \left[ \mathbf{e}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{w} \right]}{\partial \mathbf{\Phi}} = \mathbf{e}\mathbf{w}^{T} \\
\frac{\partial \left[ \mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}^{T}\mathbf{e}  \right]}{\partial \mathbf{\Phi}} = \mathbf{e}\mathbf{w}^{T} \\
\frac{\partial \left[ \mathbf{e}^{T}\mathbf{\Phi}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Phi}^{T}\mathbf{e} \right]}{\partial \mathbf{\Phi}} = 2 \mathbf{\Sigma}^{T}\mathbf{e}\mathbf{e}^{T}
\end{equation}

The 4th term drops, but I don't know how to find the derivatives for the remaining higher order terms 5, 6, and 7. Any suggestions? Is what I did correct so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of typing, I'm going to use
$$\eqalign{
 v &= \mathbf{\hat{t}}\cr
 P &= \mathbf{\Phi} \cr
}$$
The term you are asking about can be written using the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
 f &= v^TC^{-1}v \cr
   &= C^{-1}:vv^T \cr
}$$
Its differential is
$$\eqalign{
df &= C^{-1}:d(vv^T) + dC^{-1}:vv^T \cr
   &= C^{-1}:2\,{\rm sym}(dv\,v^T) - C^{-1}\,dC\,C^{-1}:vv^T \cr
   &= 2\,C^{-1}v:dv - C^{-1}vv^TC^{-1}:dC \cr\cr
}$$
Now we need expressions for $(dC, dv)$ in terms of $dP$.
$$\eqalign{
 v &= Pw +B^{-1}e \cr
dv &= dP\,w \cr\cr
 C &= B + PA^{-1}P^T \cr
dC &= 2\,{\rm sym}(dP\,A^{-1}P^T) \cr
}$$
Substituting
$$\eqalign{
df &= 2\,C^{-1}v:dP\,w - C^{-1}vv^TC^{-1}:2\,{\rm sym}(dP\,A^{-1}P^T) \cr
   &= 2\,C^{-1}vw^T:dP - 2\,C^{-1}vv^TC^{-1}PA^{-1}:dP \cr
   &= 2\,C^{-1}v(w^T - v^TC^{-1}PA^{-1}):dP \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial P} &= 2\,C^{-1}v(w^T - v^TC^{-1}PA^{-1}) \cr\cr
}$$
In these manipulations, I've made use of the fact that $A$, $C$ (and their inverses) are symmetric.

I've also made extensive use of the algebraic properties of the Frobenius product, such as
$$\eqalign{
  A:BC &= AC^T:B \cr
  X:YZ &= Y^TX:Z \cr
  A:B  &= B:A \cr
  A:B  &= A^T:B^T \cr
  A:{\rm sym}(B)   &= {\rm sym}(A):B \cr
  A:{\rm skew}(B)  &= {\rm skew}(A):B \cr
  {\rm sym}(A):{\rm skew}(B)  &= 0 \cr
}$$
all of which can easily be verified from the definitions 
$$\eqalign{
 A:B &= {\rm tr}(A^TB) \cr
 {\rm sym}(A) &= \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T) \cr
 {\rm skew}(A) &= \frac{1}{2}(A-A^T) \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, and especially for listing the properties above. This was very helpful in understanding what you did! Now, for the full derivative, is the following correct? \begin{equation} \frac{\partial L}{\partial {\bf \Phi}} = \ \mathbf{C}^{-1}\left( \left[ \mathbf{\hat{t}}\mathbf{\hat{t}}^{T}\mathbf{C}^{-1} - \mathbf{I} \right]\boldsymbol{\Phi}\mathbf{A}^{-1} - \mathbf{\hat{t}}\mathbf{w}^{T} \right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Btw I will totally upvote your nice and detailed answers, but can only do so once I gained 15 reputation.